# Rebind using new QUdpSocket

Tags: qt, data-binding, udp

I have a network application which uses UDP broadcasts for device discovery, but only accepts one connection at a time. So, when a new TCP connection is made, I delete the QUdpSocket that was used for discovery.

However, when the remote device is disconnected, I want to create a new QUdpSocket and start listening again:

```
    // Set up a UDP server to respond to any "discovery" messages:
    udpServer = new QUdpSocket(this);
    if (udpServer -> bind(QHostAddress::Any, DISCOVERY_PORT))
        connect(udpServer, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
                this,      SLOT(beDiscovered()));
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "UDP port not bound successfully: %d, ", udpServer ->error());
        fprintf(stderr, udpServer ->errorString().toLocal8Bit());
        fprintf(stderr, "\r\n");
        fflush(stderr);
#ifdef WIN32
        _commit(_fileno(stderr));
#else
        fsync(_fileno(stderr));
#endif
    }
```

The re-bind fails, however, with code 8, "The bound address is already in use".

So, how can I make sure that when the 'old' QUdpSocket was deleted, it fully releases the address(es) it was bound to?

Alternatievly, should I be binding with QUdpSocket::ShareAddress or QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint? This doesn't seem right, as neither really describe the behaviour I want, namely an exclusive binding for my QUdpSocket during its lifetime, and in any case QUdpSocket::ShareAddress is supposed to be the default on Windows.

Thanks,
Stephen.

Comment: I just noticed something. The code quoted above is inside a Qt "slot". When the remote host disconnects, the slot is getting called twice in rapid succession. The first time it looks like the UdpSocket is set up correctly, so the second time it creates another new QUdpSocket using the same pointer and finds it can't bind this - hardly surprising.

Comment: Enclosing the above code in an "if (!udpServer)" block fixes the problem for now, but I guess I now need to find where the spurious signal is coming from that causes the slot to be called when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...so in other words the question has answered itself!